# How to allow a vector input in Matlab GUI `edit text`

Tags: matlab, user-interface, vector, input, matlab-guide

The code below will work if the numerical input is a single scalar, but won't work if it is a vector. I would like the user to input the vector in the format of `[5 5 5]`.

```
handles.brightness = str2double(get(hObject,'String'));
```

I would like to store the vector values in an empty array `zeros(1,3)`. Then I could do something like `handles.brightness(1)` or `handles.brightness(2)` to use the vector elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [str2num](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) instead of str2double:

```
a = str2num('[5 5 5]')

a =

     5     5     5

>> a(2)

ans =

     5

b = str2double('[5 5 5]')

b =

   NaN
```

str2num is more flexible than str2double but there is a cost in security and performance. See the docs for details.